# errors when creating webpack config file

Tags: visual-studio, reactjs, webpack

I am trying to setup the simplest possible typescript+react-project in visual studio 2017.

I have this webpack.config.js that was changed to work with webpack 2+
The change was from using "loaders" and "preloaders" to "rules".

With the content below I get the error

> Module build failed: error TS5014: Failed to parse file 'C:\Users\my project\tsconfig.json': Unexpected token } in JSON at position 4521.

This is the file

```
module.exports = {
entry: "./Scripts/hello-stackoverflow/index.tsx",
output: { filename: "./dist/bundle.js" },


// Enable sourcemaps for debugging webpack's output.
devtool: "source-map",

resolve: {
    // Add '.ts' and '.tsx' as resolvable extensions.
    extensions: [".ts", ".tsx", ".js", ".json"]
},

module: {
    rules: [
        // All files with a '.ts' or '.tsx' extension will be handled by 'awesome-typescript-loader'.
        { test: /\.tsx?$/, loader: "ts-loader" },

        // All output '.js' files will have any sourcemaps re-processed by 'source-map-loader'.
        { enforce: "pre", test: /\.js$/, loader: "source-map-loader" }
    ]
},
externals: {
    "react": "React",
    "react-dom": "ReactDOM"
}
```

};

Comment: Show your tsconfig not webpack config...

Comment: Hi Andrew! Thanks for making me see this! I was making changes in the other file and did read the error message :/...I t seams I had and extra comma-char,. Now I get a bunch of other errors instead, but Ill post that in another questsion